# In Boolean Algebra what is the difference between AB vs A.B notations?

Tags: boolean-algebra

In Boolean algebra is `AB` the same as `A.B` and if not what are the differences between them?

And going along those same lines is `C(A+B)` the same as `C.(A+B)`

Comment: Pretty sure they're the same.  In most areas of mathematics, $\cdot$ is used as an optional notation to denote "multiplication".

Comment: That will do nicely!

Comment: It is simply a convention, much as in algebra, where the concatenation of two (or more) variables stands for the product of the two (or more) variables. I do not favor the convention, because sometimes it leads to the writer forgetting the scope of the omitted operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely no difference other than the representation of $A\land B$ used to express "and".

We have other ways of representing $A$ and $B$, as you point out: $A.B = A\cdot B = A*B = AB$.   In Boolean Logic $ A+B:=A\lor B$, and $AB=A\cdot B = A\land B$.

In computer coding, we often see $A\land B = A\&B$.

They are all various ways to express the conjunction, or the "and"-ing of two variables A, B.

Each context of study will emphasize one or the other, and a teacher in boolean logic will likely have a preference consistent with the text chosen for the class.